# Absolute parent absolute child padding and height

Tags: html, css, padding

I have following setup. Parent has 10px padding (with 56% padding top to retain its height) and I am want for a absolute child to inherit 10px padding. I can set child position top, left, right, bottom to 10px but this is a mess. If I change child to relative, it loses its height. Could I force its height to parent height with relative in this case?

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="content">
lorem ipsum dolor
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I read it 3 times and didn't get what you want ...

Comment: If you want the `content` to inherit padding from parent, why not do `.content { padding: inherit; }`

Comment: And note, the `padding-top: 56.25%;` will overwrite the short-hand value `padding: 10px` for the top value. If you want both, use a pseudo element on `slide` for the `padding-top: 56.25%;`

Comment: I just want the absolute content div to have the same padding without adding 10px margin on it or setting position to 10px. Or make it relative and behave the same.